# How to access the page front-matter data in 11ty from the code of a custom tag (shortcode)?

Tags: shortcode, custom-tag, yaml-front-matter, eleventy

In Eleventy (11ty) the page source can define custom data in it's front-matter. E.g.:

```
---
title: this is front-matter data
---
Page content
{% myCustomTag valueOfArg1 %}
```

where the custom tag (also known as shortcode in Eleventy) is generating extra content based on a configured function handler:

```
eleventyConfig.addShortcode('myCustomTag', function(arg1) {
    // how can I access here the page front-matter data? E.g. "title"
    return `<div>...${ arg1 }...</div>`;
});
```

How can I access the page front-matter data in the code of a custom tag (shortcode)?

What I want to achieve is defining a custom tag (shortcode) that has **optional** arguments. If no arguments are supplied, the arguments are searched in the front-matter:

```
---
arg1: my value
---
Page content
{% myCustomTag %}
```

and the `myCustomTag` handler function:

```
eleventyConfig.addShortcode('myCustomTag', function(arg1) {
    // if arg1 missing, search page front-matter for arg1
    // arg1 = arg1 || this.page.data.arg1 || 'default';
    return `<div>...${ arg1 }...</div>`;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the page/backup variable through to the shortcode as another parameter?

Comment: The shortcode should have access to the template context using `this`, try if `this.arg1` contains the value you need inside your shortcode callback.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a shortcode with the `function` syntax (aka not an arrow function), the function will have access to the [`page` data values](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-eleventy-supplied/#page-variable-contents) through `this` ([docs](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/nunjucks/#access-to-page-data-values)).

Unfortunately, there isn't access to the front matter, but you can read the file and parse the front matter yourself. Eleventy uses `gray-matter` internally, so it should already be installed.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const matter = require('gray-matter')

module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
  eleventyConfig.addShortcode('myCustomTag', function(arg1) {
    const str = fs.readFileSync(this.page.inputPath, 'utf8')
    const data = matter(str).data
    console.log(data.arg1)
    // use data however you want
    return
  });
}
```

If you're generating a lot of pages, it *might* help to use an [`async` shortcode](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/nunjucks/#asynchronous-shortcodes) (also available for [Liquid](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/liquid/#asynchronous-shortcodes)), but in my (very limited) testing it didn't make a huge difference (though you'll have to try for yourself).