# How to get page title in config file in Eleventy JS?

Tags: javascript, eleventy

I need to insert the title of the page in the ALT attribute. How to get the title? The code below is located in the .eleventy.js file

Right now I get the title if I pass in the props "title". But how to get the header without passing the props?

```
eleventyConfig.addShortcode('image', (src, className, title) => {
let classNameValue = (className) ? className : ' '
let titleValue = (title) ? title : ' '

    let cloudinary =
      'https://res.cloudinary.com/dr24pbwrs/image/upload/q_auto,f_auto/'
    let pathimg = src.replace(
      new RegExp('https://res.cloudinary.com/.*/image/upload/', 'g'),
      ''
    )

    return `<picture class="${classNameValue}">
                            <source
                                srcset="${cloudinary}w_768/${pathimg} 768w,
                                ${cloudinary}w_1024/${pathimg} 1024w,
                                ${cloudinary}w_1024/${pathimg} 1240w"
                                sizes="(min-width: 320px) 768px,
                                (min-width: 768px) 1024px,
                                (min-width: 1024px) 1240px,
                                100vw">
                            <img src="${cloudinary}${pathimg}" alt="${titleValue}" loading="lazy" />
                        </picture>`
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want to use a regular function, not fat arrow, and that gives you access to the page object, *but*, you do not get access to the front matter. However, you know where the file is now and can use `gray-matter` to read it in. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67746326/52160) explains how to do it.